# How to stream wma files in html (windows media files)

Tags: html, audio, web

how to stream windows media files in html without downloading
the file ?
i tried with html audio,embeded tags but wma files are  not supporting

```
<audio controls="mycontrol" height="50" width="50">
 <source src="music.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
 <source src="music.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
<embed height="50" width="50" src="music.mp3" />
</audio>
```

any other way to stream or play wma files ?

Answer (score 4):

You can't. No browsers support that format.

Convert your audio files to a supported format. (MP3, for instance; everything supports that.)

Comment: any easy way for converting to mp3 at runt time ? linux and and java is my server side .